# What is the structure of "to do would have been"?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

> Legally, the straightforward thing **to do would have been** for the Supreme Court to act according to the black and white law, and reinstate Mr. Verma, the CBI Director, and leave it there

What is the structure of "to do would have been"?

Comment: Do you mean the grammatical structure?

Answer (score 1):

The highlighted words **to do would have been** is not a single clause. The word pair *to do* belongs to the previous part of the sentence as,

> the straightforward thing to do

This can be interpreted as

> the straightforward action

The clause **would have been** is the *past conditional perfect* tense. It indicates, in this case, an alternative action that the author considers the *subject* (the Supreme Court) *could have taken* instead of whatever action they *did* take in this case.